# Remove marker from map

Tags: google-maps, jquery-ui

I'm using this code to select location from map by clicking on it . Every time I click on the map it selects a new location and shows a new marker on the map. I want to hide/remove/clear the old marker from the map. How to clear the marker from the map by a click of button ?

```
var placedMarkers = 0;
var availableMarkersToPlace = 1;
setTimeout( function(){
    if(placedMarkers >= availableMarkersToPlace)
         return;
    placedMarkers++;
    var map = Appery("google_map").gmap;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
       localStorage.setItem('selectedLat', event.latLng.lat());
localStorage.setItem('selectedLng', event.latLng.lng()); 
        placeMarker(event.latLng,map);  
        alert(event.latLng);



    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: How you store  the   reference to the old marker?

Comment: This question is too vague. How do you want to remove them? Button click? Link? Double Click? Maybe try googling this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Answer (score 0):

You should store the markers you create in a proper var eg:

```
var my_old_marker
```

then when you create a new marker firts you should set hide this marker using  setMap(null)

```
my_old_marker.setMap(null);
```

the you should create the new marker and store in my_old_marker

```
my_old_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
 });
```

If you want make a collection of markers  and eventually hide ..
you should  use an array eg:

```
var markers = [];
```

then with a listener on click you can add the marker using a function addMarker

```
    map.addListener('click', function(event) {
      addMarker(event.latLng);
    });

  // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
  function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
```

and last you can use a button for calling a function for delete the markers when you need

```
    function deleteMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Sorry , I may need to rephrase my question for clarity ... This code places markers every time the user clicks on the map. Is there a way to only place one marker on every click?How can I do it where the marker will just be moved?